# How to Properly Implement an Abstract Syntax Tree in PLY?

Tags: python, parsing, compiler-construction, lexer, ply

Hi guys I am relatively new to compiler designing, I am seeking some assistance in regards to creating an AST as well as performing semantic checks and code generation on the tree. Please see the source code for my parser below. Also to note. The implementation for my lexer is working fine so I have chosen to omit it.

```
import ply.yacc as yacc
from adapscriptlexer import tokens
from Node import*

precedence = (
    ('nonassoc','GE', 'LE', 'EQ', 'NE', 'GT', 'LT', 'OR'),
    ('left', 'ADD', 'SUB'),
    ('left', 'MUL', 'DIV'),
    ('right', 'UNARY')
)


def p_program(p):
    '''program : programStart'''
    p[0] = p[1]

def p_programStart(p):
    '''programStart : FUNC INIT "(" ")" "{" statements "}" '''
    
def p_statements(p):
    '''statements : statement
                | statements statement
                '''
    
                 
def p_statement(p):
    '''statement : function_calls
                | condition
                | function_declarations
                | expression
                | loops
                | RETURN expression
                | PRINT "(" expression ")"
                | assignment
                '''
                
                
def p_function_declarations(p):
        '''function_declarations : function_declaration'''

def p_function_declaration(p):
        '''function_declaration : FUNC IDENTIFIER "(" ")" ":" datatype "{" function_body "}" '''
        

def p_function_body(p):
        '''function_body : statements'''

def p_function_calls(p):
    '''function_calls : IDENTIFIER "(" ")"
                     | IDENTIFIER "(" ")" function_calls
                     | IDENTIFIER "(" parameters ")" 
                     | IDENTIFIER "(" parameters ")" function_calls'''
                     
def p_parameters(p):
    '''parameters : parameterList'''

def p_parameterList(p):
    '''parameterList : parameter
                    | parameter "," parameterList'''

def p_parameter(p):
    '''parameter : datatype IDENTIFIER'''

def p_datatype(p):
        '''datatype : INT
                    | FLOAT
                    | STRING
                    | ADAPT
                    | VOID'''
                    

def p_expression(p):
        '''expression : atoms
                    | paren_expr
                    | binary_expr'''
            
def p_atom(p):
        '''atoms : INT_VALUE
                | FLOAT_VALUE
                | STRING_VALUE
                | variable'''
                
def p_variable(p):
    '''variable : IDENTIFIER '''

def p_paren_expr(p):
        '''paren_expr : "(" expression ")"'''

def p_binary_expr(p):
        '''binary_expr : atoms ADD expression
                    | atoms SUB expression
                    | atoms MUL expression
                    | atoms DIV expression
                    | atoms OR expression
                    | atoms LE expression
                    | atoms GE expression
                    | atoms EQ expression
                    | atoms NE expression
                    | atoms GT expression
                    | atoms LT expression
                    | UNARY atoms
                    | atoms UNARY'''
        p[0] = BinOpNode(p[2], p[1], p[3])
                    
def p_assignment(p):    
        '''assignment : datatype IDENTIFIER EQUAL expression 
                      | datatype IDENTIFIER EQUAL ACCEPT "(" ")" '''

def p_condition(p):
        '''condition : IF expression "{" statements "}"
                    | IF expression "{" statements "}" ELSE "{" statements "}"'''

def p_loops(p):
        '''loops : loop
                | loop loops'''
        

def p_loop(p):
        '''loop : forLoop
                | whileLoop'''
        

def p_forLoop(p):
        '''forLoop : FOR "(" expression ";" condition ";" expression ")" "{" statements "}"'''
    
def p_whileLoop(p):
        '''whileLoop : WHILE "(" condition ")" "{" statements "}"'''

def p_error(p):
    print(f"Syntax error at line {p.lineno}, position {p.lexpos}: Unexpected token '{p.value}'")
   
   

parser = yacc.yacc( debug=True)
try:
    input = open("input3.txt", "r") 
except EOFError:
    print("End of file Error")
result = parser.parse(input.read())



if result is not None:
        print(result)
```

I have a utility class of Node that is supposed to in theory create nodes for various operations and evaluate these nodes:

```
    def __init__(self, type, children=None, leaf=None):
        self.type = type
        if children:
            self.children = children
        else:
            self.children = []
        self.leaf = leaf

    def semantic_analysis(self):
        raise NotImplementedError("Subclass must implement semantic_analysis")
    
class BinOpNode(Node):
    def __init__(self, operator, left, right):
        super().__init__('binop', children=[left, right], leaf=operator)

    def semantic_analysis(self):
        # Perform semantic analysis on the operands
        for child in self.children:
            child.semantic_analysis()

        # Check that the operands are of the correct type
        left_type = type(self.children[0].leaf)
        right_type = type(self.children[1].leaf)

        if self.leaf in ['ADD', 'SUB', 'MUL', 'DIV']:
            if not (left_type in [int, float] and right_type in [int, float]):
                raise TypeError("Operands must be integers or floats for arithmetic operations")
        elif self.leaf in ['GE', 'LE', 'EQ', 'NE', 'GT', 'LT']:
            if not (left_type == right_type):
                raise TypeError("Operands must be of the same type for comparison operations")

    def evaluate(self):
            left_value = self.children[0].evaluate()
            right_value = self.children[1].evaluate()

            if self.leaf == 'ADD':
                return left_value + right_value
            elif self.leaf == 'SUB':
                return left_value - right_value
            elif self.leaf == 'MUL':
                return left_value * right_value
            elif self.leaf== 'DIVIDE':
                if right_value != 0:
                    return left_value / right_value
                else:
                    raise ValueError("Division by zero")
```

I have only managed to implement the binary operation thus far. Any insight and assistance would be greatly appreciated.